# Separate numpad with keyboard and left-hand-dvorak layout together?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

This is a hardware config question. I have a keyboard with no numpad. The keyboard layout I use is left-hand-dvorak (for one-hander). I recently got a separate usb numpad. The problem is that because my system keyboard layout is set to left-hand-dvorak, the new usb numpad keyboard is not typing the proper numbers, instead letters and symbols as the system keyboard layout setting is messing with the usb numpad input. How can I have the main keyboard set to left-hand-dvorak layout, and also at the same time have the extra usb numpad set to normal US-English layout so that the numpad types numbers correctly? I am using Windows 10 on this PC. Thanks in advance if anyone can help me sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. This is one of those fancy Ducky mechanical numpads, which has additional functions and pretty RGB backlighting. One of the functions was able to set the numpad to behave normally as a numpad should.